# Why is the user logged out after closing the browser?

Tags: identityserver4, .net-6.0

I use Identity Server and .Net 6. Configure Authentication:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.ReturnUrlParameter = "requestedUrl";
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.Authority = "IdentityServer";
        options.ResponseType = OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.CodeIdToken;
        options.ClientId = "IdentityClientId";
        options.ClientSecret = "IdentityClientSecret";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SignedOutRedirectUri = websiteSettings.Home;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.Scope.Add("ordering-api");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            // .. some events
        };
    });
```

What I want is that when I authenticate the user to my web app, they can close the browser, and when they open it back, they can still use my website - they are not logged out (yet).

When I open browser I don`t see IDS cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You have to indicate in your controller method (POST: signin) where you sign in the user that you want to have persistent login.

```
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(<ApplicationUser>, isPersistent: <boolean>);
```

Here 2nd parameter must passed `true`. Default is `false`.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.signinasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-signinmanager-1-signinasync(-0-system-boolean-system-string)

Comment: Thanks. But I don`t use SignInManager. But I found IDS cookies are session. How it change to expire date? And I added picture

Comment: I add isPersistent and after reopen browser user session safe. But if I go to other app which use IDS user does not authenticate. Why fix it?